# If a cell has a duplicate take value from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

As you can see cell A4 with the quantity of B4 has a duplicate in cell A24 with quantity of B24. There is an 8 and 4 in total.

How can I find this kind of duplicate and sum them together?

[image: Screenshot of Excel data]

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kEYS.jpg

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried PivotTable? This will easily create a list of the unique values from the column A and the sum of the corresponding values in column B. Moreover, the PivotTable can also show how many duplicates for each value were found. Yes, this task can be solved with formulas, but still, first try the pivot table on the Insert tab. Also, with a few clicks, you can get the result using PowerQuery (on the Data tab)

Comment: thanks , it seems fine for my purpose . but if i want to use formula for this what should i do?

Comment: In any case, you will need to select unique values from column A. AFAIK, Excel 2016, which you indicated in the tag, did not contain the [**UNIQUE() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e), which would greatly simplify the task. So you must either [**use a filter**](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/unique_items_in_the_list.html) or use a [**rather complex formula**](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/).

Comment: After that, the usual [**SUMIF() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) will calculate the sums for each of the selected values. So? So, it won't be easy Try a PivotTable or PowerQuery - it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PivotTable to get the result directly:

Select the Range- go to **Insert**- **PivotTable**- drag Fields to areas:
[image]

For formula, try this method:
Copy column code to the new Column- select the new column and go to **Data**- **Remove Duplicates**:
[image]
[image]

Enter the formula:

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$30,F2,$B$2:$B$30)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you  very much